# Why are these line heights varied?

Tags: emacs

Note the attached screenshot from my Emacs 24. It is in Fundamental mode, no visual line mode is turned on, and I don't think I've turned on any word wrap mode either:

[image]

You can clearly see that the lines at the bottom are closer together than the lines at the top, but I have no idea why.. it's all just text? Why is emacs doing that?

This is the mode I am in:

[image]

Update: It just occured to me that perhaps this issue is that I am copying/pasting this text into emacs as I take notes from a PDF I am reading. Perhaps emacs is somehow getting formatting based from this copy/paste? I thought this was a text-only file with no formatting, but perhaps that is not true?

Comment: It looks like the line ending of the last line may be causing an issue, but I'm not sure how to fix it. Have you tried `visual-line-mode` instead of `word-wrap`?  You say `no word wrap`, but your image is clearly demonstrating `word-wrap` being active.  Essentially, there are three main choices -- truncate, word-wrap, or visual-line-mode.  Because the words are broken in the middle, you do not have `visual-line-mode` activated.

Comment: @lawlist I've updated the question. Wouldn't word wrap appear in the mode listing at the bottom of emacs if it was turned on?

Comment: That is strange, because `visual-line-mode` keeps whole words together, whereas your screen shot breaks up whole words.  The screen-shot behaves like `word-wrap`.  I do see your point, however, which would appear to indicate that `word-wrap` is disabled.  Do you experience the same problem with other major modes such as a programing mode, or a text-mode?

Comment: and incidentally it shows "wrap" when visual line mode is turned on, and remove the word "wrap" when that mode is turned off. the `vl` remains either way, and so does the line height issue @lawlist

Comment: @lawlist also i have not encountered this issue when I'm not in "Fundamental" mode

Comment: I recommend disabling `global-visual-lines-mode` and try a text-mode-hook like this:  `(add-hook 'text-mode-hook (lambda () (visual-line-mode 1) ))`  Then see if the behavior persists in `text-mode`.  At that point, `word-wrap` and `truncate-lines` should be disabled by default (at least it is in a fairly recent version of Emacs Trunk).  If necessary, grep and find the `global-visual-lines-mode` references so that you can disable it in your personal preferences and third-party libraries.  If you have `word-wrap` or `truncate-lines` enabled, then disable them also.

Comment: Could you try `M-x fringe-mode` with `none`? Just to look whether the spacing problem remains the same?

Comment: I presume Emacs calculates a wrong height for the “fancy” quoting characters in the first and the second line, and thus adds more vertical space between the lines than needed.  At least, this is the only apparent difference between the lines.  It'd also explain, why you see this issue when pasting from a PDF:  Typically these quotation marks appear in PDFs, but many users hardly ever type them on a keyboard.

Comment: You could try `M-x set-buffer-file-coding-system` and then input `us-ascii`. This may fail and give you the characters which cannot be encoded. Those characters could have fancy properties (such as mentioned by lunaryom). To investigate it further you could also extend the text by some standard ascii lines to see whether the problem also occurs there.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers everyone, it was indeed the unusual quote symbols, both apostrophes and quotation marks, that caused the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is due to unusual quote symbols, both apostrophes and quotation marks, that are affecting the line heights. Removing these and using "normal" quote marks resolves the issue.